# SELECTING records based on unique date and counting how many records on that date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that I'm going to simplify. Here's what it looks like:

```
tid     session    pos       dateOn
-----------------------------------------------
1         23        0        12/24/2020 1:00:00
2         23        1        12/24/2020 1:01:23
3         12        0        12/24/2020 1:02:43
4         23        2        12/24/2020 1:04:01
5         23        3        12/24/2020 1:04:12
6         45        0        12/26/2020 4:23:15
```

This table tells me that there were 2 unique sessions 12/24/2020 and 1 on 12/26.

How do I write my SQL statement so that I get a result like this:

```
date             recordCount
----------------------------
12/24/2020            2
12/26/2020            1
```

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Serverr?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: . . SQL Server 2008 reached the end of life in 2019 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to convert to a date and aggregate:

```
select convert(date, dateon), count(distinct session)
from t
group by convert(date, dateon)
order by convert(date, dateon);
```

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I need... at least i think. Currently there's only 1 record in the db but as it accumulates i'll know more. If i wanted to filter by month, how would I do that? WHERE month(dateOn)='12' AND year(dateOn)='2020'?

Comment: You would use `where dateOn >= '2020-12-01' and dateOn < '2021-01-01'`.

Comment: sounds like a plan. Is there a reason not to use the way i wrote it? i mean with the month() and year()?

Comment: @Damien . . . That prevents the use of indexes.